# How do I make readline() exit on Ctrl+C?

Tags: c, readline

I need to make readline exit when it encounters <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

```c
if (chkCmd(1, farg[0], "INPUT$")) {
    cerr = 0;
    ftype = 1;
    if (fargct > 1) {cerr = 3; goto fexit;}
    if (fargct == 1 && fargt[1] != 1) {cerr = 2; goto fexit;}
    outbuf[0] = 0;
    char* tmp = NULL;
    if (fargct == 1) {
        tmp = readline(farg[1]);
    } else {
        tmp = readline("?: ");
    }
    if (tmp != NULL) {
        copyStr(tmp, outbuf);
        free(tmp);
    }
    if (debug) printf("input output: {%s}\n", outbuf);
    goto fexit;
}
```

I have no clue how to do this without modifying the source code of readline (which I want to avoid at all costs). I have tried `rl_set_signals();` and `rl_clear_signals();` but those do not work.

I have done numerous Google searches only to come up with irrelevant results so I assume this question is a first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rl_getc_function = getc;
```

Changing readline's getc function works due to getc returning -1 on a Ctrl+C, which causes readline to return NULL.